# C# infinite loop for checking parameter which is a button

Tags: c#, input, infinite-loop

So I need to start a motor using a parallel port. Check if "Stop" button has been pressed and in that case stop the program and check if the bottle is too high and if it is start motor two, let it work for 3 seconds then stop it and run motor one and check again. Forever.

What I am asking you is how to run an infinite loop(for constantly checking the input) while being able to actually make an input. To clarify for this program my cue to start the motor is a button. My stop cue is also a button and checking the height is actually checking if I pressed a button. There are no actual motors instead I just have a textbox saying weather motor one and two are running are running.

Comment: Please share your code so far you have done.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand your question. Infinitive checking it's not a good way in this case. 
When I wrote an aplication to run some stepper motor Ive just implemented a bool flag 'isRunning'. When the state of this flag has changed, event "onStateChanged" raised and then I made all necessary actions and changes in controls. Hope it will help you to understand the process.